# Windows sees broken Android phone, no directories

Tags: data-recovery

So a friend brought me their Samsung Galaxy S7 phone with a broken screen, the phone *does boot* and my Windows 7 machine recognizes the phone *however* there are no directories or files listed. Edited screenshot:

[image: Phone recognized but no directories or files]

I've spent an excessive amount of time searching for anything *relevant* and there are no directories or files on another person's Windows 10 laptop.

How do I force the phone to reveal the files so I can cover them for my friend? Critical note: please only answer if you're willing to provide sufficient steps without skipping anything critical (as 90% of tutorials and videos have failed miserably at this).

Comment: Did the device have a secure lockscreen (pin, password, etc) configured? By default many devices will not give access to their storage over USB unless they are unlocked, in an attempt to prevent drive-by file theft.

Comment: Like eldarerathis said maybe is problem there. And maybe it's problem with that, that you need to allow access after phone is connected via USB to PC that is also anti theft feature, because of some incident were airports or someone else were collecting data via wall USB sockets. What is the device?

Comment: Have you cleared cache for "external storage" and "media "?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје No idea if I hooked it up to my computer; there is definitely a way to override this security mechanism; the question is *how*.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat No idea what that is or if that is relevant. I can't do anything with the phone directly except turn it on after the battery drains and adjust the volume while it is turned on. The data cable between the screen and the motherboard was completely severed because you know, why not.

Comment: Even my phone on 4.2.2 can't be accessed until you confirm the prompt which you get when connect to PC or at least it prompt a window to choose type of connection. What I can see that is phone Galaxy S7 and mtp connection, so as I said you can't access storage until confirm "allow this computer to access phone data" I doubt there is a way to recover data on broken screen phones, at least for us mortals. Maybe there is some paid software to access storage in this situations but I don't think it will work if encrypted and most phones are encrypted by default.